# How to force the table orders in Latex

Tags: floats, longtable

I have several tables and some of them are long tables. LaTeX displays them in different order than I want.

Say, I would like to order them as

```
table 1
table 2
table 3(longtable)
table 4
table 5
table 6(long table)
```

But LaTeX orders it like

```
table 1
table 2
table 3(longtable)
table 6(long table)
table 4
table 5
```

How can I force the order as I want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Latex floating tables never float out of order. However as is mentioned in the documentation `longtable` doesn't float so tables can float past it, out of order. The simplest solution is to put `\clearpage` before the `longtable` to prevent floats floating past.

Comment: @user16739: If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking the check mark underneath the vote count to the left and to upvote it.